# Use SQL Query to convert a base64 string back into an image

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that will convert an image in a base64 string format back to an image and save to the file system.

Comment: I won't be a surprise for me if it is not possible to write a file with SQL.

Comment: The only chance I see to do this would be to create a SQL-CLR assembly in C# that has this functionality, and integrate that into SQL Server. "Native" T-SQL has no functions for neither Base64 encoding/decoding, nor for image manipulations of any kind

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above, I can't accomplish what I want using pure SQL.  Will call C# code from SQL instead.